# How to print the lowest value in an arrayList using OOP?

Tags: java, loops, oop, arraylist

I was expecting get the lowest run time, but instead it prints the very last entree in the arrayList. I'm trying to print a specific course for the dogs and that works when I enter the course code. However, the lowest run time seem to not work.

example data

Lazlo     12.2

Rin       34.2

Yu        23.3 - This will be printed as the winning dog when Lazlo should be the winning dog.

The winning dog should have the lowest run time, but it takes in the last read line instead and prints it.

```
private void winningDog(String dogsCode) 
{
    double runTime = 300;
    String winningDog = "";
    double winningTime = 0;
    for (Dogs dog: dogsList)
    {
        if(runTime > dog.getTotalTime() && (dog.getCourseCode().equalsIgnoreCase(dogsCode)))
        {
            winningTime = dog.getTotalTime();
            winningDog = dog.getName();
        }

    }
    System.out.printf("%n%s%17s%20s%1.2f%n", 
          "Winning dog", winningDog,"Time " , winningTime);

}
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow! On your journey of programming, you'll find debugging is a very valuable skill. In the beginning, printing out variables can really help. My hint is to print your variables in the beginning of your for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't have negative values for `dog.getTotalTime()`, you can change your code

```
winningTime = Double.MAX_VALUE; //assigning MAX value to ensure the condition is met at least once(unless all your time values are MAX_VALUE)
```

and then update your condition as

```
if(runTime > dog.getTotalTime()..
```

to

```
if(winningTime > dog.getTotalTime().. // this would compare winningTime and you're setting the same is the condition matches
```

Comment: Thank you! I've never used this code before but it fixed my problem :). Thank you so much.

Comment: @NicoRobin welcome. If this works please be kind enough to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is basically finding the minimum field of some object. You can do this in one line using the new Java 8 Stream API.

```
Dogs winningDog = dogsList.stream().min(Comparator.comparingInt(Dogs::getTotalTime)).get();
```

Your class `Dogs` should probably be `Dog`. I'm just basing my response based off your enhanced for-loop, where it says `Dogs dog: dogsList`.

Your filter in the for-loop can easily be chained into the call by adding a `.filter( CONDITIONS )` in-between `.stream()` and `.min()`.

Comment: I would use `Collections.min()`.

Comment: `Comparator.comparingDouble()` for time comparison instead.

Comment: @shmosel using this code doesn't seem eclipse to like it. I tried the Collections.sort before, but it gave me an error even with package imported.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void winningDog(String dogsCode) {
    String winningDog = "";
    double winningTime = 0;
    if (dogsList != null) {
        winningTime = dogsList.get(0).getTotalTime();
        winningDog = dogsList.get(0).getName();
        if (dogsList.size() > 1) {
            for (int i = 1; i < dogsList.size(); i++) {
                if (dogsList.get(i).getTotalTime()< winningTime
                        &&  (dogsList.get(i).getCourseCode().equalsIgnoreCase(dogsCode))) {
                    winningTime = dogsList.get(i).getTotalTime();
                    winningDog = dogsList.get(i).getName();
                }

            }
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("%n%s%17s%20s%1.2f%n", "Winning dog", winningDog, "Time ", winningTime);
}
```

Comment: I did. Tho it's printing the highest value instead of the lowest value.

Comment: @Hiccup The comparator sign within `if` seems to be wrong. It has to be `>`